# How can I compile SASS using TFS online?

Tags: css, visual-studio, tfs, sass

I'm using visualstudio.com's hosted TFS to build our project.  We recently introduced SASS, which is compiled locally for the developers in VS 2013 Update 4, with Web Essentials installed.  How can I make the online version of TFS compile the SASS into CSS?  Checking in the compiled CSS and map files would be a nightmare for merging.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you're building an MVC app, you can use MVC's bundling feature along with the [SASS NuGet package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/BundleTransformer.SassAndScss/1.6.9). And, be sure to enable minification. There's a UseNativeMinification property on SassAndScssSettings.

Comment: Yeah, I'm doing all that on the dev machines.  My issue is that when we check in to cloud-hosted TFS, and the CI build kicks off, it doesn't know how to complile the SASS to CSS.  Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Are you restoring the SASS NuGet package as part of your build process, or have you checked all your packages into version control?

Comment: OK, so....I switched over to using gulp to compile my SASS.  Any ideas on how I can run gulp in the cloud-hosted TFS?

Comment: thanks for your comments...i figured it out.  had to execute a bat file on pre-build on the server that actually did the install of the gulp components and then called the sass compile task

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your comments...i figured it out.  had to execute a bat file on pre-build on the server that actually did the install of the gulp components and then called the sass compile task